# Php 5.3 file_name

Tags: php

To upload an image via a html form with

```
<input name='img' id='img' type='file' size='16'>
```

I used to retrieve the file name with php variable `$img_name` in my scripts.

This seems to fail on php 5.3 servers but I can't find any documentation about that.
Do I need to rewrite my scripts using the `$_FILES["img"]["name"]` variable ?

Comment: Sounds like register globals is turned off which is a *good* thing.

Comment: This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: Indeed had no idea this even existed. Good thing I didn't even learn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your script is working only with register globals turned on, which is disabled in default in PHP 5.3.

You can turn it on, but definitely better will be rewrite your script to use global arrays like `$_FILES` or `$_POST`. Especially that in PHP 5.4 will be no option to turn it on again. Check this http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php